# Replace last newline character in file with a semicolon

Tags: mysql, bash

I have taken a dump of a mysql table, and I'm appending several create tables in a row - only problem is there is no semi-colon at the end of each create table.

What I'd like to do is as I capture each individual "show create table" is replace the very last "\n" with a ;

Can someone please suggest how I do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

> master_file.sql
> tmp.sql

while read line
do
    mysql --skip-column-names -u root -pxxxxxxxxxx test -e "show create table $line" > tmp.sql
    sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' tmp.sql
    #echo ';' >> tmp.sql
    cat tmp.sql >> master_file.sql
    echo "" >> master_file.sql
done < table_list
```

My output is as follows:

```
hours   CREATE TABLE `hours` (
) DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
;

user_session_view       CREATE TABLE `user_session_view` (
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
;
```

The semicolon should be immediately to the right of "latin1" or "utf8" in this case, but it isn't.

Comment: Why aren't you using `mysqldump`? It outputs all the needed semicolons.

Comment: What's wrong with the output you have? There's no rule that says that the semicolon has to be on the same line as the query.

Comment: No semicolons were produced when exporting "CREATE TABLE" syntax.

Comment: But you add it with `echo ';' >> tmp.sql`

Comment: Where did the semicolons you show in "My output is as follows" come from?

Comment: If you see the code I commented out that line because they weren't putting them in the right place.

Comment: What do you mean by "the right place"? Why is it wrong for them to be on the next line?

Comment: right place = intended behavior with my code.

Comment: MySQL doesn't care, why does your code care?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking advantage of the fact that "process substitution" removes last newline:

```
printf %s "$(< tmp.sql);" > tmp2.sql
```

In your case, you can combine sed and this:

```
printf %s "$(< tmp.sql);" | sed 's/\\n/\n/g' >> master_file.sql
```

Note that the output file should be different than the input file.

---

A solution with awk could be:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print l} {l=$0} END{ORS=""; print($0 ";")}' tmp.sql >> master_file.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something with `sed`

test.txt

```
create table (
) default charset=latin1

create table (
) default charset=utf8

test
```

sed and result

```
sed -r 's|(charset=)(.*)|\1\2;|g' test.txt > newtest.txt

cat newtest.txt

create table (
) default charset=latin1;

create table (
) default charset=utf8;

test
```